# Wordpress - https : Css and Js files are not working (load on http instead of https)

Tags: css, https, http

i have moved my website to another server and changed the domain name, then i installed an SSL certificate, and when i change my website form http to https in wp-options and wp-config and also set a redirection to https in .htaccess my website didn't work only if i use http://mywebsite.com

and when i change the http to https://mywebsite.com via chrome tab the JS and CSS file only load http and the website doesn't look as it must

Comment: it's not enough to redirect CSS/JS to https, browsers will not attempt to load HTTP assets on a HTTPS page for security reasons, even if they redirect to secure locations

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in to wp-config.php just before - **require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';** line

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: Thank you i'll try this one

Comment: That's for reverse proxies though. It doesn't sound like that's the problem here to me.

Comment: this worked on my load balanced server. Thanks.

Comment: I had this one in wp-config.php but it needed to go as well to wp-settings.php for me

Answer (score 1):

What URL are you using in the WordPress general options (`/wp-admin/options-general.php`)? HTTP or HTTPS? You should make sure you put your HTTPS address there.

Also it might help to re-save your permalinks.

Comment: Can you be please more specific ? is there a function a should look for in order the check HTTP/HTTPS... i'm newbie to wordpress Sorry

Comment: @Norman Go to `yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options-general.php` (when logged in). There you'll see two text input's with your website URL. Can you validate if you see your website URL with HTTPS (instead of HTTP)? Alternatively, you can go to Settings → General (same thing).

Answer (score 0):

You can try some Apache code in your .htaccess file to redirect any http to https. And make sure wordpress settings are pointing to https and not http.

```pm
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  "www.domain.com"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Sorry about syntax highlighting. Not sure what the language code is for Apache directives on here.