# Redirect Css files to https

Tags: css, https

where can i find the file responsible for calling the Css files and test if their links are http or https ?

i want to test the request if https, if so it's good to go and if not change it to https

in Functions.php i have found the function responsible on calling the theme Css, here is its code :

```php
if (!function_exists('jobcareer_front_scripts')) {

    function jobcareer_front_scripts() {
        global $jobcareer_options;
        if (!is_admin()) {
            /*
             * Css Files
             */
            wp_enqueue_style('jobcareer_iconmoon_css', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/iconmoon.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('cs_bootstrap_css', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/bootstrap.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('jobcareer_style_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('jobcareer_nav-icon', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/nav-icon.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('jobcareer_top-menu', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/top-menu.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('cs_slicknav_css', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/slicknav.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('jobcareer_widgets_css', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/widget.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('jobcareer_prettyPhoto', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/prettyPhoto.css');
            if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
                wp_enqueue_style('cs-woocommerce', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/cs-woocommerce.css');
            }

            // color style 
            $custom_style_ver = (isset($jobcareer_options['jobcareer_theme_option_save_flag'])) ? $jobcareer_options['jobcareer_theme_option_save_flag'] : '';
            wp_enqueue_style('jobcareer_custom_style_css', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/css/custom-style.css', '', $custom_style_ver);

            /*
             * Js Files
             * 
             */

            if (isset($jobcareer_options['cs_maintenance_page_switch']) and $jobcareer_options['cs_maintenance_page_switch'] == 'on') {
                wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_addthis_widget_js', '' . cs_server_protocol() . 's7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4e4412d954dccc64', '', '', true);
            }
            wp_enqueue_script('cs_bootstrap_min_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_modernizr_min_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/modernizr.min.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_browser_detect_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/browser-detect.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('cs_slick_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/slick.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_jquery_sticky_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/jquery.sticky.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_map_styles', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/cs_map_styles.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_functions_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/functions.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_menu_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/menu.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_prettyPhoto_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_lightbox_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/lightbox.js', '', '', true);

            if (is_singular() && get_option('thread_comments') && get_comments_number()) {
                wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
            }

            /*
             * Include scroll js enqueue files functions 
             */
            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_scrolltofix')) {

                function jobcareer_scrolltofix() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_sticky_header_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/sticky_header.js', '', '', true);
                }

            }

            /*
             * Include scroll js enqueue files functions 
             */
            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_jquery_easing_js')) {

                function jobcareer_jquery_easing_js() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_jquery_easing_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js', '', '', true);
                }

            }

            // Start Include  Counter Script enqueue files functions 
            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_counter_script')) {

                function jobcareer_counter_script() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_counter_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/counter.js', '', '', true);
                }

            }

            /*
             *  Include slick Script enqueue files functions 
             */
            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_enqueue_slick_script')) {

                function jobcareer_enqueue_slick_script() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('cs_slick_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/slick.js', '', '', true);
                }

            }

            /*
             * Start Include Count Script enqueue files functions 
             */
            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_enqueue_count_nos')) {

                function jobcareer_enqueue_count_nos() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_countTo_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/jquery.countTo.js', '', '', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_inview_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/jquery.inview.min.js', '', '', true);
                }

            }

            /*
             * Start Include Ticker enqueue files functions 
             */
            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_news_ticker_script')) {

                function jobcareer_news_ticker_script() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_news_ticker_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/ticker.js', '', '', true);
                }

            }
            /*
             *  End Include Ticker enqueue files functions 
             */

            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_google_map_script')) {

                function jobcareer_google_map_script() {
                    global $jobcareer_options;
                    $google_api_key = '?libraries=places';
                    if (isset($jobcareer_options['cs_googleapi_key']) && $jobcareer_options['cs_googleapi_key'] != '') {
                        $google_api_key = '?key=' . $jobcareer_options['cs_googleapi_key'] . '&libraries=places';
                    }
                    wp_enqueue_script('cs_google_autocomplete_script', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js' . $google_api_key);
                }

            }

            // Start Include Slide Menu enqueue files functions
            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_sliiide_menu')) {

                function jobcareer_sliiide_menu() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_sliiide_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/sliiide.js', '', '', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_nav-icon_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/nav-icon.js', '', '', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_jquery.slicknav_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/jquery.slicknav.js', '', '', true);
                }

            }

            /*
             * Start Add this soocial sharing enqueue Script
             */
            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_addthis_script_init_method')) {

                function jobcareer_addthis_script_init_method() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_addthis_widget_js', '' . cs_server_protocol() . 's7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4e4412d954dccc64');
                }

            }

            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_dynamic_scripts')) {

                function jobcareer_dynamic_scripts($cs_js_key, $cs_arr_key, $cs_js_code) {
                    // Register the script
                    wp_register_script('jobcareer_dynamic_scripts', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/cs_inline_scripts_functions.js', '', '', true);


                    // Localize the script
                    $cs_code_array = array(
                        $cs_arr_key => $cs_js_code
                    );
                    wp_localize_script('jobcareer_dynamic_scripts', $cs_js_key, $cs_code_array);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_dynamic_scripts');

                    wp_enqueue_style('jobcareer_dynamic_scripts');
                }

            }

            if (!function_exists('jobcareer_gallery_masonry')) {

                function jobcareer_gallery_masonry() {
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_init_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/init.js', '', '', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_freetile_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/jquery.freetile.js', '', '', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jobcareer_masonry_pkgd_min_js', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'assets/scripts/masonry.pkgd.min.js', '', '', true);
                }

            }
        }
        jobcareer_inline_styles_method();
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: There isn't a single file responsible for enqueing CSS, the answer will be different depending on which CSS file you're referring to, and which plugin/theme it belongs to. Generally, all assets should be HTTPS to avoid mixed content errors

Comment: im referring to the theme Css

Comment: @TomJNowell   i have found the file `Functions.php` and now how can i please check if this function `function jobcareer_front_scripts()` called https or http, cause i need all 
css links to be https. Thank you

Comment: You would need to share the code for that function in your question, use the edit link under the tags to update it and add the info in a code block

Comment: Noting that this is related to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392867/wordpress-https-css-and-js-files-are-not-working-load-on-http-instead-of-ht

Comment: @TomJNowell i have added the function code, and now i need to force url to be https if not already. 
Thank you so much for your replies

Comment: Almost all of those use get_template_directory_url(), which ultimately uses your site URL. Is your site URL https? The others use cs_server_protocol() which must be provided by your theme - it's not WordPress core.

Comment: Indeed, note that the browsers dev tools will tell you which files are being blocked due to mixed content issues, and that all the scripts and styles that rely on `get_template_directory_uri` will be HTTPS if your WP is set up to be HTTPS. The ony script in that code we can say anything with certainty about is the Google Maps autocomplete script which is HTTPS as we can see `https://` in the code

Comment: Also note that your questions title talks about redirecting CSS to https, for which there is a definitive answer: No that's not how mixed content warnings work, you can't redirect a http to a https to make it work, browsers won't even attempt it so will never discover the redirect, and if they did they wouldn't trust it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You Just change the `http` to `https`in your `site_url` and `home_url` field in the `wp_options` table.

Hope it will works.